# How to use foreach inside subst in Tcl (template iteration)?

Tags: templates, foreach, tcl

Does anyone know how if there is a way to include a foreach loop in the subst command, to get a pseudo-template effect?

For example, the following works:

```
set lim 3
set table sldkfjsl
set sqlpat {
     select * from $table limit $lim
}
set sqltext [subst $sqlpat]
```

But I would like to do something like

```
set sqlpat {
    foreach i {1 2 3} {
        select * from ${table}_$i limit $lim;
    }
}
set sqltext [subst $sqlpat]
```

And have it give three separate lines of sql:

```
select * from sldkfjsl_1 limit 3
select * from sldkfjsl_2 limit 3 
select * from sldkfjsl_3 limit 3
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

(EDIT, my solution which sort of shows how build a strfor command that can be used in a subst template, in my case for passing both SQL and gnuplot code to their respective programs):

```
proc strfor { nms vals str } {   
    set outstr ""
    foreach $nms $vals {
        append outstr [subst $str]
    }
    return $outstr
}

set foostr1 {select $a from table_$b;\n}
set x [strfor {a b} {A 1 B 2 C 3 D 4} $foostr1]

set foostr2 {


    blahsd line 1
    blahg line 2

    [strfor {a b} {A 1 B 2 C 3 D 4} {
        forline1 $a $b
        forline2 $b $a
    }]

    blah later 
}

puts [subst $foostr2]
```

Comment: You're almost there. Hint: what you want is a list of SQL statements.

Comment: Hehe.  I might have it soon, but I am still interested in a more general solution.  I also think I need to play uplevel games...

Comment: No no, you don't need `uplevel`. Think really simple. I haven't tried it myself yet, but I don't think you need any commands beside those you've already used. OK, `lappend` will probably be useful too.

Comment: Yeah, you were right -- simple is better.  I put my full, successful experiment in my question above.

Comment: Sorry I wasted your time. If I had known you were going to do it that way I would have posted my suggestion earlier.

Comment: Well, I hope I didn't waste your time, but you didn't waste mine.  It's all practice for us both and a resource for later coders.  I didn't think it would be so easy.

Comment: It occurs to me that my previous comment could be interpreted as me saying that your solution wasn't worthwhile. Your solution is of course good both _as_ practice and _in_ practice, just slightly overkill in this case. And I'm on staycation, so I have way too much time to fiddle with stuff like this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The looping commands in Tcl do not return values, so they are useless in a string which is processed with `subst`. It is of course possible to write an accumulating looping command as you have done. Another possibility is to use `lmap`. However, the problem can be solved in an easier way.

```
set lim 3
set table sldkfjsl
```

We're going to make a list where every item is an instance of a literal template with variable substitutions. First we create an empty list:

```
set sqlpats {}
```

Then we loop for each value in the sequence 1..3. For every iteration we append an instance of the template to the list:

```
foreach i {1 2 3} {
    lappend sqlpats "select * from ${table}_$i limit $lim"
}
```

(`subst` isn't necessary here, ordinary variable substitution is sufficient.)

Create a resulting string from the list, with newlines between each item (yep, I was wrong, one more command was needed):

```
join $sqlpats \n
```

ETA:

`subst` is one of those commands which is nice to have, but that I for one almost never use. For most purposes, simpler measures will do. Once in a while though, a convoluted bit of code leaves a string unsubstituted. I pick up `subst` out of the drawer and *zap!* That said, the ability to selectively allow or disallow different kinds of substitutions alone makes `subst` very worthwhile.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm)

Comment: +1 in particular for the remark "subst isn't necessary here..."; I keep using `subst` in code only to return a few weeks later to find that there was no need.

Comment: @nurdglaw: I classify `subst` as one of the don't-use-it-yet commands. One can usually do without it, and as you say it can often be refactored out later. But when it's really useful, it's indispensible.

Comment: I used subst in the above solution because I am writing a proc that builds a script (either gnuplot or SQL) in the above scope using that scope's variables, but it isn't necessary in the returning foreach.  I would be interested in alternative approaches, though.

Comment: @forkandwait: have you looked at the pages discussing `subst` on the Wiki? http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/search?S=subst Some people there are a lot more fond of using `subst` than I am and have built templating tools on it.

Comment: @hoodiecrow: yes, I looked, but they seemed too heavy weight for me, though inspirational.  Also, the tclers wiki suffers from wiki-entropy, so I don't rely on it all the much.

Comment: `lmap` does return values.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: yes, it does. It's not a looping command in the strict sense of the word, though. You'll note that I mentioned it as being useful in a template.

Comment: `lmap` is a nice replacement for `foreach` in codegolf.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: since it was introduced, it has replaced `foreach` in many places in both production and recreational code. But it still isn't a looping command, unless one changes the definition of what a looping command is, in which case I'd simply have to say "Except for `lmap`, the looping commands in Tcl do not return values [...]".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: yes, a lot of commands return values; the looping commands don't. The `dict` command is an ensemble command, not a looping command, though it does have a looping subcommand. After invoking `dict` with that subcommand in the argument pattern, the command returns a value as it always does.